# Google Sheets, how to find and sum all numbers in a given string/category

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have made a google sheets. Where I want to find all my expenses, but only expenses under one category/related to one thing. (could be "School")

I want to know how much I have spend under a specific category "daligvarer" and sum the "udgift" expenses made there.

[image]

I have tried  this
`=VLOOKUP("Daligvarer",J26:L30,2,0)`. I get 22,95 kr (the first of on the list)
and this
`=sum(VLOOKUP("Daligvarer",J26:L30,2,0))`. I get 22,95 kr (the first of on the list)

I only get the first expensive with the specific string "daligvarer", and not a sum of all the numbers with that string
I have tried some googling and videos, can't seem to find the help, therefore asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **[`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)** ?

```
=SUMIF(O154:O162,"="&"aa",P154:P162)
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Perfect. It works, just what I wanted and needed. Ty so much